# Runtime-Type of T in IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, reflection, iqueryable

Is there a possibility to get the T-Runtime type of an IQueryable?
If it's a normal list, there is no problem, but if I check against an IQueryable, I always get a type of System.Object.
My code is looking like this at the moment:

```
private static Type GetDtoTypeFromDataSource(ReportDataSource dataSourceFromDb)
{
    Type result = null;
    if (dataSourceFromDb.Data.GetType().IsGenericType)
    {
        Type[] genericArguments = dataSourceFromDb.Data.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
        result = genericArguments.First();

        if (result == typeof(Object))
        {
            var obj = dataSourceFromDb.Data.Cast<object>().ToList();

            var t2 = obj.First().GetType();
            var t = obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
            var t3 = obj.GetType();

            result = obj.GetType();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = dataSourceFromDb.Data.GetType().GetElementType();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I hoped, if I actually load the List via "ToList" I get the Data, but doesnt work as well.

```
var t2 = obj.First().GetType();
```

Would to the trick, but what if the List is empty? This doesn't seem like a good solution to me?

Comment: Do you want [IQueryable.ElementType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.iqueryable.elementtype(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: How is `ReportDataSource.Data` declared? It can't be just `IQueryable<T>`. Most likely, it is declared at compile time as `IQueryable<object>`, which is why `object` is the type you're seeing.

Comment: Uff, you was right Dmytro, one overloaded Constructor took an IEnumerable and castet it to Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compile-time type of `Data` will always be the same. From what you're describing, it sounds like it is `IQueryable<object>`. This is why you always get `System.Object` when you try to examine the type.

As to the *run-time* types of actual objects stored in this collection, you have to examine the objects in a way similar to what you've shown in your question:

```
dataSource.Data.First().GetType();
```

Comment: You were right. The problem was a bit more complex: One of our Constructors to an IEnumerable instead of an ICollection and casted it via .Cast<Object>, which is a nice Hack, but doesn't work with Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Considering query is `IQueryable<T>`

```
var typeOfT = query.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
```

Works for me

Comment: That should work, which is why this doesn't answer the question. Because clearly dataSource.Data is not an IQueryable<T>.